# Is there a template to display a tri-fold or page-turn for a portfolio?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, portfolio, template-design

I'm building my portfolio, and rather than handing out hundreds of various designs, I want to put several items on one page. But I also want to illustrate what they are, such as a tri-fold or magazine.

Is there a template to show the folded item, or magazine pages to actually look like a magazine, rather than a flat image?

I've tried skewing the folded item in photoshop, but I couldn't get the angle right; and I tried vanishing point, but without an actual item to compare to, the angle was even worse than the skew.

I'm OK with Photoshop, Illustrator, or InDesign.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually BoxShot ([boxshot.com](http://boxshot.com/)) can help with this... I'm sure there are free alternative out there as well.

Sometimes the best option is to photograph the actual work rather than trying to fake it with software.

Answer (score 2):

http://medialoot.com/item/tri-fold-brochure-mock-up-template/

This one is very easy to use straight in Photshop. It's free too.
[image: Trifold Brochure Mockup]

Answer (score 1):

I either photograph the piece or in the case that I don't have that option I'll generally find a stock photo of the object and superimpose my work on top.

Its of course going to depend on specifically what you're doing but for book covers and spines for example I'll just find a high resolution stock image of a book and then drop my own cover art and spine into place using distort to first get the corners just right and then warp to add any subtle bend.

Then tweak the lighting to match the original cover usually by way of soft gradients.