# How do I create a mock-up photorealistic book and graphics and what free tool could be used?

Tags: photo-editing, mockup

Can you create illustrations (see below) with indesign?

[image: Example Illustration]

[image: Example Illusrtation]

I would like to create this content and offer PDF brochures to visitors and make it look much better. However, I am not sure if this is possible and how to do it.

I'd like to find out free tools to do that those small book-looking illustrations. Something like upload a cover and then it puts it on a digital book. Like those websites which promote only one book and you can see different illustrations of the cover and so on.

In order to promote brochures, PDF files, ebooks, and so on.

[image: Something Like This]

I mean an ebook cover which is shown as a small illustration from the side angle so it looks nice. Not actually the ebook itself, just the cover and make it look like a real book, presentable from a side angle. Was wondering about Abobe Indesign but would like to find out free tools to do that. Something like upload a cover and then it puts it on a digital book. Something like that. Like those website which promote only one book and you can see different illustrations of the cover and so on. –

Comment: To be able to help you, please show us what you have tried and explain where you think it goes wrong. To show some effort would make it easier to get answers. Having said that, InDesign is not really the sw for this kind of thing. You would be better off with Illustrator, Inkscape, Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: I would imagine you are asking how to create the mockup correct?

Comment: I mean an ebook cover which is shown as a small illustration from the side angle so it looks nice. Not actually the ebook itself, just the cover and make it look like a real book, presentable from a side angle.

Comment: Other question was more about Abobe Indesign, with this one here I like to find out free tools to do that those small book-looking illustrations. Something like upload a cover and then it puts it on a digital book. Something like that. Like those website which promote only one book and you can see different illustrations of the cover and so on.

Comment: @PeterHelp then what is your other question supposed to be asking? You need to be specific in your questions because right now they look identical. I also just answered how to do a cover in that other question.

Comment: Hi there. I don't see much difference between this one and your other question. Why don't you add info from this one in the other? They can both be answered in a single one. I paste your comment there. Feel free to add any more info.

Comment: i have done so, thx for advice! i hope i can learn from you guys!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a template to display a tri-fold or page-turn for a portfolio?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/is-there-a-template-to-display-a-tri-fold-or-page-turn-for-a-portfolio)

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Adobe InDesign has some very limited illustration capabilities via the Pen Tool and the Shape Tool and Direct Selection Tool. Unfortunately it is not suited to creating anything more than basic geometric shapes and very simple wordmark based logos.

Ideally you would use Adobe Illustrator to create logos and vector based images and you would bring them into InDesign as assets for your Ebook.

Here is a link to a video briefly explaining [why Illustrator is used for Logo Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI4c5MAP_V4).
Ultimately you can use another vector program and import these assets but InDesign works very well when used with other Adobe products like Illustrator and Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

You won't create mockups like these with InDesign.

For this kind of work I would recommend using one of the many available Photoshop templates, because the time and expense of creating something from scratch is beyond the budget of most small projects like this.

You can find a large number of mockup templates, both commercial (but inexpensive) or free, by searching "mockup templates" on Google. Most require CS4 or later, because they use Smart Objects to make it easy to substitute your own images for the ones in the template. One such source is [pixeden.com](http://www.pixeden.com/psd-mock-up-templates), which offers both free and commercial templates.

[Psdcovers.com](http://www.psdcovers.com) publishes an enormous collection of Photoshop Action sets that build a complete mockup from scratch. These include many hardcover and softcover book templates, CD and DVD covers, tote bags, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of [free graphic software](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/free-graphic-design-software-8134039).

Brochures and eBooks are typically InDesign territory, so look for an equivalent of that. [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) seems to be a popular one, although I've never used it myself. Related discussion [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/840/scribus-vs-indesign-or-quark-is-it-a-viable-alternative)

Answer (score 0):

For free you're going to want to look into Gimp. You don't entirely create the book model. You find a royalty free version you can either license or is available under an applicable open license. Then bring that into Gimp and edit the front cover and spine. That will be a lot easier for you than trying to draw a book and pages from scratch.